# React Fullcalendar: Allow user to manually change the order of calendar events by dragging them above or below each other

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

I am using the FullCalendar component and the DayGridMonth plugin/view to schedule out tasks in a system, and it would be ideal to order tasks within each day cell depending on their priority.

Currently the only solution I have came up with is each event having a priority and then allowing the user to increase or decrease the priority in a details view that appears when you click on the event. The events are then ordered by priority. However, this is not ideal and it would be preferable to simply drag the events above or below each other.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't think fullCalendar supports this - it only allows dragging and dropping based on time grids. So you'd have to write a completely custom set of code to enable it.